# Connecting to Azure SQL database from local WCF

Tags: sql, azure, connection-string, azure-sql-database

I have a WCF web service and local data instance working perfectly on my local machine. I have create an instance of the database on azure and what to connect the web service to it to ensure it is working before I host to web service on Azure too.

I have setup a connection string to my local database which works at the minute therefore I assumed I just needed to change this to my new azure connection string, however this is not working. See working connection string VS non working on and how I'm implementing my code in DAL below.

Current/Local connection String

```
<add name="VervePhaseOneConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SNICKERS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VervePhaseTwo;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

New azure connection String which isn't working

```
  <add name="VervePhaseOneConnectionString" connectionString="Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=VerveDB;User ID=bradleya@server;Password={passwordString};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

DAL code that uses connection string

```
SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection();
            oConn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VervePhaseOneConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            oConn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = oConn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_addSessionPlay";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string looks correct to me.  However, to check it, you can login to your Azure account and click on the SQL Database and view the connection string.  It will give you the different examples needed.

[image]

Also, I assume you've checked the firewall settings in Azure?

Good luck.

Comment: Yes checked the firewall settings I can access it on the web interface. For reference VS is throwing an SQL exception - A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)

Comment: Have you looked at Allowed Ip Addresses?  I think it's called Manage allowed IP Addresses?  You'll be able to connect using web interface, but application needs your IP included in this list to connect.

Comment: Yes its definitely in the allowed IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that your machine/network's firewall bloacking outbound connection to port 1433. try to add a exception rule in your machine/network firewall setting for port 1433.